# JAVA-ThreadPoolExecutor why we need to judge the worker count in the execute function during the recheck procedure?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I understand that we need to recheck if the TPE is running when we add a new task, but my question is why we need to judge if the workerCountOf(recheck) is equal to 0? My understanding is that if the TPE is running during the recheck, the task will guaranteed to be executed by the TPE. So I think it is the TPE's responsibility to check if there is any thread left to execute the task, not the submitter!

so am i right ?

the code as below:

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    int c = ctl.get();
    if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
        if (addWorker(command, true))
            return;
        c = ctl.get();
    }
    if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
        int recheck = ctl.get();
        if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
            reject(command);
        else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0) // ????
            addWorker(null, false);
    }
    else if (!addWorker(command, false))
        reject(command);
}
```

Comment: If there is no worker, who will pull the workQueue (that the command was just added to)?

Comment: I mean how could this happen? what is the scenario?

Comment: The code above is from the Java class `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`?  I'd say it's doing internal housekeeping and call it a day.  Why is the internal implementation important?

Comment: I think this would happen when you have a core pool size of 0. Then you need to create a first thread when the first job arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example,

Suppose corePoolSize = 1. When check first time, there is only one worker.
 Between `if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize)` and `workQueue.offer(command)`, the only worker finished its job and find no job in the block queue, so it exists. When recheck, `workerCountOf(recheck) == 0` happens. We need to start a new worker.

CorePoolSize not always equals the real count of worker. Every workercould die after they finish their job and find no job in the block queue within a limited time.

Comment: Actually if you look at the [`ThreadPoolExecutor.execute` source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#ThreadPoolExecutor.execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29) there is a comment that states the same. Particularly it says "_So we recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if stopped, **or start a new thread if there are none**._". I'm not sure what John misses in that comment.

Comment: Yeah, an example will make it easier to understand "if there are none".

Comment: Much clearer now !  I do see the comment, but I thought that the TPE is RUNNING means that it has threads RUNNING which is terribly WRONG !  Now I figure it out ! Thank you both !

Answer (score 0):

But a core thread never quits when it has finished working, even if there are no tasks in the queue